# Compare same string in two different encodings fails

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, encoding

I am trying to filter a large json file based on a list of strings which I get from a tsv file by calling

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.tsv", header = 0, sep = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
names = df['name'].tolist()
```

I am sure that all of the strings of the list are json keys, but when I do the filtering I get less results back than the length of the name list due to the fact that the names of the list and the keys of the json objects seem to have different encodings (?).

For example in my list as printed out by python

```
l = ['Boro StjepanoviÃÂ']
```

and its equivalent in the json file as printed out by python

```
{'Boro Stjepanović': ['Boro Stjepanović', 'Borislav Stjepanović', 'Боро Стјепановић', 'بورو ستجيبانوفيك', 'Bosnian', 'Herzegovinian', 'actor', 'Borislav Boro Stjepanović', 'Boro Stjepanovic', 'Борислав Стјепановић', 'Bora Stjepanović', 'Boro Stjepanović', 'male', 'Sterija Award for Achievement in Acting', 'human', 'Vareš']}]
```

How could I make sure that these two match?

Edit: part of output of hexdump -C example.tsv

```
00000000  6e 61 6d 65 09 73 75 6d  6d 61 72 79 09 77 69 6b  |name.summary.wik|
00000010  69 70 65 64 69 61 0d 0a  62 6f 72 6f 20 73 74 6a  |ipedia..boro stj|
00000020  65 70 61 6e 6f 76 69 c3  83 c2 84 c3 82 c2 87 09  |epanovi.........|
00000030  22 42 6f 72 69 73 6c 61  76 20 22 22 42 6f 72 6f  |"Borislav ""Boro|
00000040  22 22 20 53 74 6a 65 70  61 6e 6f 76 69 c3 83 c2  |"" Stjepanovi...|
00000050  84 c3 82 c2 87 20 28 62  6f 72 6e 20 38 20 4d 61  |..... (born 8 Ma|
00000060  79 20 31 39 34 36 20 69  6e 20 56 61 72 65 c3 83  |y 1946 in Vare..|
00000070  c2 85 c3 82 c2 a1 2c 20  53 52 20 42 6f 73 6e 69  |......, SR Bosni|
00000080  61 20 61 6e 64 20 48 65  72 7a 65 67 6f 76 69 6e  |a and Herzegovin|
00000090  61 2c 20 53 46 52 20 59  75 67 6f 73 6c 61 76 69  |a, SFR Yugoslavi|
000000a0  61 29 20 69 73 20 61 20  42 6f 73 6e 69 61 6e 20  |a) is a Bosnian |
```

Comment: Could you share a few lines of `hexdump -C example.tsv`?

Comment: Hi, I added it as part of my question!

Comment: thanks, I mean some part where you have these weird symbols. Just to see what encoding the tsv file actually uses.

Comment: Sorry, I now pasted part of what I get for Boro Stjepanović's line in the tsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your input appears to be "double over-encoded", that is, someone mistakenly encoded UTF-8 data into UTF-8... twice ;(

You can clean this up in python:

```
with open('example.tsv', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

data = data.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

or use `iconv` twice:

```
iconv -t iso-8859-1 -f utf-8 example.tsv > temp1
iconv -t iso-8859-1 -f utf-8 temp1 > example.tsv
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks! I'll let the other team know they're doing something wrong.